# Angular Service Testing - How is the Expected Value Being Returned?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to figure out how to test services, and the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests) reference this [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjvemqrgqrjv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.service.spec.ts).

I can't understand *how*, in the `it('should return expected heroes (called once)'` test that the assertion passes. I don't see any mock or spy set up to return `expectedHeroes` when the `getHeroes()` function on the service is called, so how is that happening?

```
describe('#getHeroes', () => {
    let expectedHeroes: Hero[];

    beforeEach(() => {
      heroService = TestBed.get(HeroesService);
      expectedHeroes = [
        { id: 1, name: 'A' },
        { id: 2, name: 'B' },
       ] as Hero[];
    });

    it('should return expected heroes (called once)', () => {
    //------------------------------------------
    // HOW IS THIS PASSING???

      heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
        heroes => expect(heroes).toEqual(expectedHeroes, 'should return expected heroes'),
        fail
      );

      // HeroService should have made one request to GET heroes from expected URL
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(heroService.heroesUrl);
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

      // Respond with the mock heroes
      req.flush(expectedHeroes);
    });
  });
```

Comment: It looks like `req.flush(expectedHeroes)` uses `httpTestingController` to return `expectedHeroes` from something deeper in Angular before the http call is made. So it's not `getHeroes` that is mocked directly. Then the `.subscribe` runs and the `expect` passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the implementation of `HeroesService` is, but I think I can make a pretty good guess based on the remainder of the test body.

When you call `getHeroes()`, you are getting an observable object which will be fulfilled at some later date through the `subscribe` handler. That "later date" comes up as the last line of your test.

The `httpTestingController` is (presumably) keeping track of all HTTP requests made by things within the `TestBed`, but not responding to them. When you fetch the request object (using `expectOne`), you are then able to act as though you're the remote server and populate the response.

This test is testing that `req.flush(expectedHeroes)` flushes properly through the `HeroesService` and out the other side (`subscribe`) without modification.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't notice the comment right before the `req.flush` line, but you must be right. I was just used to how it is in my real code, where calling `subscribe` actually creates the request. That and `flush` just sounds like a cleanup term to me, so I kinda skipped over it. But the Angular docs actually have an extra comment that says: `// Respond with mock data, causing Observable to resolve.
  // Subscribe callback asserts that correct data was returned.
  req.flush(testData);`